# Furnace and Water Heater Ventilation pipe

Tags: water-heater, ventilation, chimney

I have a home that was built in 1924, the pipe that vents my furnace and water heater is green and it is located in my chimney.

The top of the chimney is open in my attic, you can see the green ventilation pipe that runs out of my roof.

Should the green pipe be insulated in my attic?

Should there be something put over the top of the chimney?

Answer (score 1):

A chimney cap is a good idea, as it reduces the water heading down.  Water can affect the flames and rust the pipe.

For better answers we need to know what type of pipe (ceramic? metal? plastic?). In general chimneys are not to be insulated.  Tap on the pipe, what does it sound like?  Post pictures.  What era are the heating appliances: that matters also.  Old ones send a lot of heat up the chimney, drying it out.